# How to get a part of app's file content in cloudfoundry?

Tags: cloud-foundry

cf-java-client seems has an api getFile(String appName, int instanceIndex, String filePath, int startPosition, int endPosition) but I can't find any similar implementation in cfoundry or cf-cli.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get a portion of a file directly with the `cf` CLI. You should be able use the `cf curl` command to do the equivalent, e.g.:

`cf curl /v2/apps/{app_guid}/instances/{instance_index}/files/{file_path} -H "Range: bytes={start}-{end}"`

Comment: I try the command cf curl /v2/apps/87e04075-8830-4c96-8dc4-a54b56c6eaad/instances/0/files/app/app.js -H "Range: bytes=100-1000" but it doesn't work.